# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on receive

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a web api to upload document into sharepoint using CSOM. It is getting upload and I have to return some metadata into json format. While returning response I am getting below error.

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

I tried all around

```
webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
webRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10;
webRequest.RequestTimeout= false;
```

using .net framework 4.5.2

Comment: Hi Ravi,
Did you got any solution...?